# F12 does not render appended object in the right position

Tags: rendering

I am modelling different objects in different blend files. my plan is to then import them into 1 single onject once done. this is to save computational power on my pc (not the greatest machine on earth). I successfully import the mesh objects I need, I edit them, move them, etc. I can also see them in the render viewport. great.
when I try to render them using F12 though they appear crammed in the position they were imported at.. as if I did nothing. why is this happening ? sorry I am new to blender 2.92 and ... maybe is a trivial point

here is the viewport view
[image: viewport]
here is the rendering with F12
[image: F12]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the scene, including the outliner?

Comment: I added 2 views. In the 2nd you can see some greyed object at the base of the shelving unit which is the original imported object. Note: I imported them using append, selecting the blend file then choosing "object" and picking the ones I wanted. I did not import the whole collection.  What I don't get is why what I see in the viewport does not match F12 rendering results. I am not using frames or layers (at least not that I know :D)

Comment: I also noted that my edits are not conserved in the saved file, basically they look like the rendering result.

Comment: Is there a chance the objects location are keyframed? Then when you move them without adding or replacing keyframes the changes are not saved.

Comment: mh that is a good guess. It could be. although I have not worked with keyframes in these models. Is there a way to remove eventually the old "keyframe info" and set the new object positions and locations as new keyframes?

Comment: ok so after inserting a keyframe (and deleting the previous ones), I managed to get the object rendered in the right place. However all the other info (material and shading) is lost. mh... thanks though :) it seems that was the issue :)

Comment: Cool. I don't understand why materials and shading was lost, though.